# How to enable external monitor on Ubuntu 14.04 notebook

Tags: 14.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, fglrx, amd-graphics

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04. and now Ubuntu recognizes only built in monitor.

I tried switching driver from default to fglrx, but after that I am unable to log in, I get into log in loop - after logging in I am returned to log in screen.

I purged fglrx and logged in successfully.

Is there a way to get external monitor recognized without installing fglrx?

Comment: Have you looked in the display settings in system settings to see if its recognized ?

Comment: Sure, I did. With fglrx I can't even enter system so there is no way to see if it recognizes. Without fglrx it does not recognize other monitor.